# Rundeck log remote node commands debug

Tags: ssh, remote-server, rundeck

We have Rundeck 3.3.2 (CE) running on CentOS 7.x. We have some problems with a job, this job runs a script stored on another CentOS 7.x server, but when run it throws this error: bash: +2d: no such directory or file.

The Rundeck server has access to the node that presents the problem, since if we execute an ls or the same script through a command, it manages to connect via ssh and execute the command.

Is there a way to have a much more detailed log about what is being executed remotely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can enable the debug mode for job results, at the moment of running the job, click on the "triangle" button (at the left of the Run Job button) and select "Run with debug output". Take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX7Bb.jpg).
2. Related to your problem, make sure to set the correct interpreter for your scripts. On your inline script / script steps, click on the "Advanced" link and set the bash path in the "Invocation String" textbox, e.g.: `/bin/bash`.
3. Probably the path to copy the dispatched script is blocked by some security policies, you can define a custom path to dispatch your script with the `script-exec-dir` attribute. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/script.html#configuring-the-working-directory).

Comment: Hello, the debug at job level don't say anything new just the same error, this can be debugged at service / daemon level? Thanks.